# Variable scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is a simple question, but I can't work it out.

The specifics aren't important, but here's the gist. I have some code like this:

```
var lat = 0;
var lon = 0;

if (navigator.geolocation) {    
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        lon = position.coords.longitude;
    });
}
```

What I think it's doing is:

1. Set lat and lon to 0
2. If the browser has geolocation, overwrite those variables with real values

However, at the end of that chunk, lat and lon are still 0. I've tried adding `var`s, passing lat and lon to the function etc but with no success...

How do I make this work?

Comment: Ah, answers make a lot of sense. I knew it was async, but am not used to programming in that style. How do I specifically make this work then? After this chunk I use ajax to access an API, and don't want to repeat the code twice depending on whether we know location or not.

Comment: put the call to your other API *inside* the callback from `getCurrentPosition`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an async callback.  Basically, you pass a function to the the navigator API.  Then, your code continues (and does whatever).  Later, the navigator API calls your callback with the answer (position).  Thus, anything that uses position must be inside (including called by) the callback.

See also [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707191/unable-to-cope-with-the-asynchronous-nature-of-navigator-geolocation/2707217#2707217), which shows how you can create and use a wrapper function.

EDIT: You can simply write a function that calls your callback regardless.  If you wanted, getLocation could pass another flag to its argument (e.g. a failure/success code).

```
function getLocation(callback)
{
    if (navigator.geolocation) {    
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
    }
    else {
        callback(null);
    }
}
```

Then later:

```
getLocation(function(pos)
{
  //do stuff
  if(pos != null)
  {
    // loc stuff
  }
  // more stuff
});
```

You don't have to use anonymous functions.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the scope. `getCurrentPosition` is called asynchronously, that means it will return immediately before the position is received. The `function(position)` is called only when the geo-position is actually received.

Answer (score 1):

[getCurrentPosition()](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#get-current-position) is asynchronous - the values won't be updated instantaneously.

> The `getCurrentPosition()` method takes one, two or three arguments. When called, it must immediately return and then asynchronously attempt to obtain the current location of the device. If the attempt is successful, the `successCallback` must be invoked (i.e. the `handleEvent` operation must be called on the callback object) with a new Position object, reflecting the current location of the device. If the attempt fails, the `errorCallback` must be invoked with a new `PositionError` object, reflecting the reason for the failure.

`alert` the values from the function and you'll see the changes. Write the code to perform whatever actions you want inside the function (or abstract them to another function and call it from there) instead of continuing after the `if` block. For safety, add an error-callback too.