# Geolocation script not working

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am making a request to an app that I'm running on another server. I know my browser supports geolocation, because I've tried it elsewhere. Here is what I currently have:

```
<script>
    function getLocation(){
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition)
        }else{
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported");
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position){
        return position.coords.latitude+" "+position.coords.longitude;
    }

    (function () {
        var latlong = getLocation();
        console.log("Latlong " + latlong);
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", "http://api.example.com/", true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var params = "location=" + latlong;
        http.send(params);
        http.onload = function() {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    })();
</script>
```

The request works, but the location param is set to `undefined`. Why is it not defined?

Comment: fiddle would be great...

Comment: @JTC http://jsfiddle.net/escsofb4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to cope with the asynchronous nature of navigator.geolocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2707191/unable-to-cope-with-the-asynchronous-nature-of-navigator-geolocation)

Comment: [Using geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `getCurrentPosition` accepts three parameters like this. 
`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);`

Simply put your output function needs to be in `success`.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v605qbtm/)

Answer (score 0):

Move the Ajax request into the `showPosition` callback. At the moment you call params before it is filled.